# Please suggest any good newsletter module for drupal 7

Tags: drupal, module, drupal-7, newsletter

I am looking for newletter module for drupal 7 which should works with contact us page also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try these [Newsletter](http://drupal.org/project/newsletter) and [simplenews](http://drupal.org/project/simplenews) module.Both will provide good functionalty.

Answer (score 1):

[Simplenews](http://drupal.org/project/simplenews) publishes and sends newsletters to lists of subscribers. Both anonymous and authenticated users can opt-in to different mailing lists. HTML email can be sent by adding Mime Mail module.